# Date not visible in csv file

Tags: powershell

I am generating a report like below in a csv

```
"Index","Response","Status","Time"
"36167","2","Succeeded","2023-02-01 03:56:34.9"
"36166","3","Succeeded","2023-02-01 03:51:34.9"
"36165","2","Succeeded","2023-02-01 03:46:34.9"
```

In the server when I am opening the csv as notepad, I am able to see the `"2023-02-01 03:56:34.9"` format ( as I am not having excel in server so opening in notepad)

But the same report when I am sending via email I am getting data like

```
"36167","2","Succeeded","56:34.9"
"36166","3","Succeeded","51:34.9"
"36165","2","Succeeded","46:34.9"
```

The date is missing from the column value.

Please let me know what is the issue here

```
Send-MailMessage -from $fromEmail -to $toEmail -Cc $toCCmail1 -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Body $body -Subject "Report" -Attachments "D:\Monthly\ISL_Report_$prev_month.csv"
```

Comment: The issue is with Excel and not Powershell.  Excel guesses and column type and often guess wrong especially with dates. The data is being opened by excel when in outlook while you in the server you are using notepad. Excel is opening the column up and reading the date correctly but then decides to only display the date in short format.  the simple solution after you open up excel is to manually change the column format to the long date. You did the right think of putting double quotes around the string, but excel ignored the double quotes and converted to date and then only display short date.

Comment: You _can_ force Excel to show the format in the csv by prefixing all the 'Time' values with a TAB character. However, Excel will leave the format alone because by doing so you tell it to see the value as text, not as date. This may present new problems on sorting and the like though..